# How to navigate using nativescript-urlhandler

Tags: nativescript

I have a javascript Nativescript app (i.e., no Angular, Vue, or typescript),  What I want to be able to do is receive a text with a deep-link into my app, receive the link, and then navigate to a specific page.

I've followed the nativescript-urlhandler docs and, on iOS, can receive the url, but I don't know what to do with it once I have it.  That is, in my app.js file, I have:

```
handleOpenURL(function(appURL) {
  console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
});
```

What I want to do from here would ordinarily be a

```
frame.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
```

call, but how can I get the app's viewModel for the resulting page, since that's loaded by main-page.js (using the standard template).  That is, such navigation requests are otherwise always made from within the app where the viewModel is already set, but it's not yet set in app.js.

I've been looking for code samples but haven't found anything with straight NativeScript, so I'm posing the question to the StackOverflow-verse. Any help or insight welcome!

Comment: I've been using https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler - and can't get it to work for me... did you use this plugin, and can you advise what you did? I'm using nativescript vue... I followed the instructions for plain nativescript verbatim (so wonder if anything different is needed for vue?)

Comment: @Rob - Yes, I used the urlhandler plugin.  There are admittedly a lot of moving parts here.  What specific symptoms are you seeing, and on what platform?

Comment: Thanks @David. I managed to get it working in the end. I was writing my config in the generated plist file... not the one in App_Resources... its working now. Tonight I will be figuring out how to connect it up to nativeScripts vue router

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working.  Yes, the

```
frame.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
```

works.  What I did was create my own instance of the viewModel and set that as the binding context, such as ,

```
handleOpenURL(function (appUrl) {

  var viewModel = createViewModel(); // create own instance of viewModel
  viewModel.helpReq = parseUrl(appUrl.toString()); // add data from URL to viewModel

    var navigationOptions = {
      moduleName: './views/help-req-page',
      context: { bindingContext: viewModel }
    }
    frame.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
}
```

Where parseUrl(), predictably, parses the url and creates an object from the various components.

If I have an empty action bar on the target page, then I automatically get a  link back to my app that closes the target page cleanly.

I have this working on iOS; I have not tried Android yet.